# Unable to edit record after immediately updating the same record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a form that is used to update project status.  The main form is used to filter by name/type/status, I have no issues with that and don't believe it impacts the issue on the subform.

My subform is a datasheet who recordset is updated based on the above filters.  Status is a column in the datasheet that is a combobox. I run into an issue when I do the follow commands:
  1) Update a value within a row
  2) Try to make a second update to the same row

If I follow all three steps I cannot change a second value (or the original for that matter).  If I make a change in a new row, then no problem exists.

I've tried a few different ways to fix the issue.

For example, none of these seem to fix the issue:

```
Private Sub StatusID_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.Dirty Then
    Me.Dirty = False
End If
End Sub
```

Also, this saves but doesn't not allow me to edit without changing another row first:

```
Private Sub StatusID_AfterUpdate()
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End Sub
```

The only way I resolved the issue is by adding a button that runs Me.Refresh.  But I'd prefer if I could get access to do this automatically.  I wonder if the issues relates to the data being on a subform.

Answer (score 0):

So, typing this out made me think of something.  I assume I should leave the question if it helps anyone.

To resolve the issue I have to use the following code:

```
Private Sub StatusID_AfterUpdate()
    Forms!ProjectList.Refresh
End Sub
```

If I put just Me.Refresh, I think since the subform is active sheet it was not working correctly.  This is why the button worked, it was on the main form.